# How to fix NameError: name 'author' is not defined when running python script

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to open up this on the terminal on my mac, but I keep getting name 'author' not defined when it clearly is.

```
def bibformat_mla(author, title, city, publisher, year):
    author = input("enter author: ")
    title = input("enter title: ")
    city = input("enter city: ")
    publisher = input("enter publisher: ")
    year = input("enter year: ")
    answer = author + ' , ' + title + ' , ' + city + ': ' + publisher + ', ' + year
    return answer


bibformat_mla(author, title, city, publisher, year)
'author, title, city: publisher, year'

bibformat_mla("Jake, Matt", "Open Data ", "Winnipeg", "AU Press", 2013)
 'Morin, Pat. Open Data Structures. Winnipeg: AU Press, 2013'
```

Comment: I made the title more specific to aid in people finding this issue, I hope you don't mind.  As @Daniel Scott said below, it looks like you're trying to pass in undefined variables as the arguments in the first call, you either have to define those first somewhere, or take them out.

Answer (score 3):

When you run the following:

```
bibformat_mla(author,title,city,publisher,year)
```

You are saying to the program that you have a variable called "author" which is ready to pass into biblformat(). This causes an error because the the variable isn't defined before the function is called.

I.e You're telling the function to expect a certain variable, and it throws an error at you because the variable doesn't actually exist yet.

From what it looks like you are trying to accomplish, you can simply call the function like this:

```
bibformat_mla()
```

You will also need to change your definition to this so that your function no longer expects the parameters:

```
def bibformat_mla():
```

Comment: I tried that but, now when I try to open the program on terminal I keep getting TypeError: bibformat_mla() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'author', 'title', 'city', and 'publisher'

Comment: I've updated the answer. You'll need to take the parameters out when you define the function.

Comment: Okay, I got it, but is there some way to make the ("Enter Author") appear when I actually declare the variable in the program, instead of it asking right away when I open the program up in the terminal.

Comment: You're describing what this new code should do. Have you ran it?

Comment: Yes, I have ran it

Answer (score 0):

You need to decide whether your function will be accepting those strings as arguments or if it will prompt the user for them? There isn't much point requiring the user provide the values as arguments, then immediately overwriting them with values they enter.

So you have a choice.

1. perform the inputs prior to calling the function and pass the inputted values to the function.
2. remove the arguments to the function and allow the user to input the strings as part of `bibformat_mla`.

code:

```
def bibformat_mla1 (author,title,city,publisher,year):
    return author + ' , ' + title + ' , ' + city + ': ' + publisher + ', ' + str(year)

def bibformat_mla2 ():
    author = input ("enter author: ")
    title = input ("enter title: ")
    city = input ("enter city: ")
    publisher = input ("enter publisher: ")
    year = input ("enter year: ")
    return author + ' , ' + title + ' , ' + city + ': ' + publisher + ', ' + year

print(bibformat_mla1("Jake, Matt", "Open Data ", "Winnipeg", "AU Press", 2013))
print(bibformat_mla2())
```

Answer (score 0):

With functions you can pass information as Parameters, in your function definition you  are indicating that when you run the function you will also pass 5 variables with it.

From the looks of it you are setting the variables by user input and thus you do not need to pass parameters, deleting them should make the code work.

This:

```
def bibformat_mla(author, title, city, publisher, year):
```

Into this:

```
def bibformat_mla():
```